# Why would this function work only when I make a copy of the variable?

Tags: functions, function-construction, variable-definitions

Why would this function work with a copy of the function variable:

```
Clear[zero]
zero[list_] := Module[{listCopy = list}, listCopy[[2]] = 0; listCopy]
zero[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
(* {1, 0, 3, 4, 5} *)
```

but not when using the variable directly?

```
Clear[zero]
zero[list_] := Module[{}, list[[2]] = 0; list]
zero[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Please see my answer in the marked duplicate.

Comment: Thanks for your answer in the linked Q&A. It helps me understand on why using my function directly with the `list` will not work as the value for `list` will be directly plugged into the RHS of the equation. However, when using `listCopy`, wouldn't the value of `listCopy` be plugged in as well? (elaboration: `Clear[zero];
zero[list_] := Module[{listCopy = list}, Print[listCopy]; listCopy[[2]] = 0; listCopy]; zero[{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}]`). Does `Set` belong to a class of function (like `AppendTo` in your answer) that only takes symbol, which may or may not be associated with a value?

Comment: In answer to your last question, basically, yes.  `Set` has the `HoldFirst` attribute which keeps `listCopy[[2]]` from evaluating, and `Set` recognizes this as a special expression and perform the in-place modification.  There is controlled evaluation of the first argument of `Set` which allows patterns to expand etc., but it doesn't relate to your use here.  If you wish to know more about that let me know and I'll find relevant material.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the latter is equivalent to

```
{1,2,3,4,5}[[2]] = 0
```

which is invalid.  The former stays as

```
listCopy[[2]] = 0
```

You can't change (i.e. assign to) parts of a literal like this.   You can change (i.e. assign to) a variable.

Generally,

```
f[x_] := x[[2]]
```

will substitute the value of `x` directly.  So will `With[{x=...}, x[[2]] ]`.  In contrast, `Module[{x={1,2,3}}, x[[2]] ]` *assigns* a value to `x`, but does not directly replace `x` with `{1,2,3}` in the body of the `Module`.